# How to find the minimum of a data.frame according to the value of another variable

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this dataset

```
    > head(data,15)
    X        AIC          MSE                    data method num_var
1   0 -8767.4402 0.0001496157 A p=1000 n=1000 SNR=0.5     HF      20
2   1 -8767.4402 0.0001496157 A p=1000 n=1000 SNR=0.5     HM      20
3   2 -2385.3440 0.0913237854 A p=1000 n=1000 SNR=0.5  HMP80       4
4   3 -2340.9765 0.0958494526 A p=1000 n=1000 SNR=0.5  HMP90       2
5   4 -5242.1750 0.0050813667 A p=1000 n=1000 SNR=0.5   LP70      20
6   5 -5242.1750 0.0050813667 A p=1000 n=1000 SNR=0.5   LP85      20
7   6 -8383.1066 0.0002197310 A p=1000 n=1000 SNR=0.5    lCV      20
8   7 -2359.8396 0.0940583853 A p=1000 n=1000 SNR=0.5 rl0270       2
9   8 -2359.8396 0.0940583853 A p=1000 n=1000 SNR=0.5 rl0240       2
10  9 -2359.8396 0.0940583853 A p=1000 n=1000 SNR=0.5 rl0570       2
11 10 -2359.8396 0.0940583853 A p=1000 n=1000 SNR=0.5 rl0540       2
12 11 -2417.3708 0.0886223833 A p=1000 n=1000 SNR=0.5 RL0001       3
13 12 -5242.1750 0.0050813667 A p=1000 n=1000 SNR=0.5   lAIC      20
14 13  -949.9553 0.0039668746  C p=1000 n=200 SNR=0.5     HF      78
15 14  -949.9553 0.0039668746  C p=1000 n=200 SNR=0.5     HM      78
>
```

There are various methods and their performance (MSE) in different datasets (data). 
I would like to know how how many times each method is the best. 
So for example HF can be the minimum when data=A p1000.... .

At the end I would like a data frame where each column is a method and one row that says how many times the method was the best.

EDIT: 
Code suggested is not working

```
> head(data)
  X       AIC          MSE                    data method num_var
1 0 -8767.440 0.0001496157 A p=1000 n=1000 SNR=0.5     HF      20
2 1 -8767.440 0.0001496157 A p=1000 n=1000 SNR=0.5     HM      20
3 2 -2385.344 0.0913237854 A p=1000 n=1000 SNR=0.5  HMP80       4
4 3 -2340.977 0.0958494526 A p=1000 n=1000 SNR=0.5  HMP90       2
5 4 -5242.175 0.0050813667 A p=1000 n=1000 SNR=0.5   LP70      20
6 5 -5242.175 0.0050813667 A p=1000 n=1000 SNR=0.5   LP85      20
> DT <- as.data.table(data)
> Counts <- DT[, sum(MSE == min(MSE, na.rm=TRUE)), by=method]
> Counts <- setnames(data.table(t(Counts$V1)), Counts$method)
Error in setnames(data.table(t(Counts$V1)), Counts$method) : 
  Passed a vector of type 'integer'. Needs to be type 'character'.
> Counts
    method V1
 1:     HF  1
 2:     HM  1
 3:  HMP80  1
 4:  HMP90  1
 5:   LP70  1
 6:   LP85  1
 7:    lCV  1
 8: rl0270  1
 9: rl0240  1
10: rl0570  1
11: rl0540  1
12: RL0001  1
13:   lAIC  1
>
```

Comment: It appears method is a factor not a character.   Convert and you are fine

Comment: @RicardoSaporta Sorry I do not understand how to make it works. Can you pass the whole correct code? Should V1 be the result? It is not the value I was expecting

Comment: Hi @Donbeo, my answer was already edited with this..  please look carefully thanks :)

Comment: @RicardoSaporta sorry we should definitively learn to read the question more carefully. Anyway this report me a wrong results. If I run the code using as data the $head(data)$ reported in the question I should obtain all 0  and one to HF, HM. Instead I obtain all 1

Answer (score 0):

easiest way is to convert to a data.table

```
library(data.table)

## Convert to data.table
DT <- as.data.table(DAT)

## Make method into a character
DT[, method := as.character(method)]

## Find the smallest value by method
Counts <- DT[, sum(MSE == min(MSE, na.rm=TRUE)), by=method]

## Convert to wide, if preferred
Counts <- setnames(data.table(t(Counts$V1)), Counts$method)

### RESULTS
    HF HM HMP80 HMP90 LP70 LP85 lCV rl0270 rl0240 rl0570 rl0540 RL0001 lAIC
 1:  1  1     1     1    1    1   1      1      1      1      1      1    1
```

Comment: Hi Donbeo,  I am not sure one can do much with a comment of "it does not work as expected."   How does it not work?  What is letting you know it does not work?  What is expected?  Where does what you got differ from what you expected, etc etc